# QGIS: my styles don't appear anywhere

Tags: qgis

I created a smart group in the Style Manager, but when I save a style (using "Save Style") in the layer properties window, the styles don't appear anywhere, either in the style manager or in the regular preset window. When I'm in the style manager and try to add a style, it forces me to recreate it. I must be missing something. How do I get my styles into the style manager?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me in QGIS 3.26.3-Buenos Aires.

Save symbol in the symbology editor. Bearing in mind it's symbols you are saving. So if you wanted to save a categorised symbology you would save the style not the symbol.

When saving you should save to the default location. Unless you only want to use it for that one project.

[image]

Then it will show up in the Default styles, IF you have the correct filter on. By default only "Favourite" styles are shown.

[image]

[image]

It also shows up in the Style Manager under the label.

[image]